# How to get the name and description of a sidebar in theme?

Tags: theme-development, sidebar, register-sidebar

I have a sidebar registered (in `functions.php`) as:

```
<?php
register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => __('Activity Calendar'),
        'id'            => 'activity_calendar_en',
        'before_widget' => '',
        'after_widget'  => '',
        'before_title'  => '',
        'after_title'   => '',
    ));
?>
```

In my theme I am calling it as:

```
<?php
if( is_active_sidebar( 'activity_calendar_en' ) ):
    dynamic_sidebar( 'activity_calendar_en' );
endif;
?>
```

Now my question is: how to print the sidebar name (`Activity Calendar` in this case) in the theme? Is there any method to get and print the sidebar name (as well as any description if available)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `$wp_registered_sidebars` global variable. Like this:

```
global $wp_registered_sidebars;
if( is_active_sidebar( 'activity_calendar_en' ) ):
    esc_html_e( $wp_registered_sidebars['activity_calendar_en']['name'] );
    dynamic_sidebar( 'activity_calendar_en' );
endif;
```

If you check the WordPress core for `is_registered_sidebar` function, you'll see that it's using this global variable too:

```
function is_registered_sidebar( $sidebar_id ) {
    global $wp_registered_sidebars;

    return isset( $wp_registered_sidebars[ $sidebar_id ] );
}
```

However, as far as I know, you can't retrieve it using any function.

Although, for description there is a function: `wp_sidebar_description()`. You may use the global variable for description as well, or this function:

```
if( is_active_sidebar( 'activity_calendar_en' ) ):
    echo wp_sidebar_description( 'activity_calendar_en' );
    dynamic_sidebar( 'activity_calendar_en' );
endif;
```